# Text and Image Slider over a fixed background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, materialize

Currently, I'm working with the Materializecss Image Slider. Actually what I want is to Keep a fixed full-screen Background image and the texts and images slide over through the fixed background images.

For now, I put background-color of the slider class as transparent, but it's not Working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slider();
});
```

```css
 section {
   background: url('http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


.slider .slides {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  margin: 0;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Materialize slider</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.css">


  
</head>

<body>
  <section>
   <div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       
        <div class="caption left-align">
          <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        
        <div class="caption right-align">
          <h3>Right Aligned Caption</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </section>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/js/materialize.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your question is not clear. It'd be better if you try separating what you tried to solve and what problem you faced.

Comment: I want a slider with fixed bg-image and text and icons should slide over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the Answer for my question.

```js
function step(n){
 //$(".content-switcher").hide();
  if(n==1){
    $(".content-switcher").animate({
      "left":"-600px"
    },"slow");
  } else if(n==2){
    $(".content-switcher").animate({
      "left":"-1200px"
    },"slow");
  } else if(n==3){
    $(".content-switcher").animate({
      "left":"0px"
    },"slow");
  }
}
```

```css
.container{
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline:1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/093/696/original/vector-yellow-abstract-background.jpg");
}
.slider{ width: 1800px;}
.content-switcher{
  width: 600px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Simple Content Slider</title>
  
  
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
  <a href="#" onclick="step(1); return false;" style="color: #fff">Step 1</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="step(2); return false;" style="color: #fff">Step 2</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="step(3); return false;" style="color: #fff">Step 3</a>
  <div class="slider">
  <div class="content-switcher" id="content1">
    <p>1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
      . Saepe sint enim autem beatae sunt distinctio fugiat facilis accusamus dolorum labore quis natus culpa laudantium eos consequatur excepturi rerum error velit.</p>
      <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437">
       <p>1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
      . Saepe sint enim autem beatae sunt distinctio fugiat facilis accusamus dolorum labore quis natus culpa laudantium eos consequatur excepturi rerum error velit.</p>
      <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437">
       <p>1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
      . Saepe sint enim autem beatae sunt distinctio fugiat facilis accusamus dolorum labore quis natus culpa laudantium eos consequatur excepturi rerum error velit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content-switcher" id="content2">
    <img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/image/user_images/Starmight350-808191_384_377.jpg">
    <p>2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe sint enim autem beatae sunt distinctio fugiat facilis accusamus dolorum labore quis natus culpa laudantium eos consequatur excepturi rerum error velit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content-switcher" id="content3">
    <p>3Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe sint enim autem beatae sunt distinctio fugiat facilis accusamus dolorum labore quis natus culpa laudantium eos consequatur excepturi rerum error velit.</p>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work if you take care of the quote issue in the `section`'s `style` attribute. If you use double-quotes with `style=""` then you can't have double-quotes within those double-quotes. So you need to remove the double-quotes within that attribute or replace them with single quotes. Also `rgba(255,255,255,0)` is one way to do transparency, but an easier way is to use `transparent` - but an even easier way is just to remove that line entirely because there is no background by default, so it's transparent. Here's a working demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJwOBR

Comment: it's working, but the problem is how should I slide one image over a fixed background image.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a div with overlay class and set overlay div on the whole image like below:

Add  `div` after `<section> tag` take class name as `class="overlay"`

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Add some CSS for set overlay div on image

```
 .overlay
   {    
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
   }
```

And add CSS for display text properly

```
.caption {
position: relative;
z-index: 99;
}
```

Try this.